# Using folders to select pages

Tags: php, layout, web

I'm not really sure what this is called so i'm just looking for any information on it really.

I've seen a few websites that are using this sort of url www.domain.com/folder/1/2/3/1234/ but the numbers can be set dynamically and used as variables. I'm sure i'm a few steps behind with this but it's confusing me. Surely if you're setting 1 2 3 1234 in a folder string its going to look for folder 1234 in folder 3 in folder 2 in folder 1 in folder then back to the root?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you can modify this behavior from .htaccess so that all queries go to for example index.php, and there you parse the REQUEST_URI yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Just enable mod_rewrite in Apache and then use simple .htaccess to redirect all requests to single index.php and then parse $_GET ($_GET['route'] in the example below) parameter or the REQUEST_URI.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, so whats the benefits of using this system over traditional variables?

Answer (score 0):

The technology you are looking for is called [URL rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_rewriting).

For Apache HTTP Server there is a very popular module called [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Searching for "**mod_rewrite tutorial/guide**" will give you many relevant results.